# How do I post multiple inputs with same name and different values

Tags: php, html

I have multiple inputs with the same Name attribute and different Values, which cannot be changed by the user.

```
<form action="../scripts/sc_order.php" method="post">
    <div class="sc_content">
        <input type="text" name="product[]" value="Potato" readonly/>
        <input type="text" name="product[]" value="Tomato" readonly/>
        <input type="text" name="product[]" value="Banana" readonly/>
        <input type="text" name="product[]" value="Orange" readonly/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The inputs are added to the form and they serve as an identifier for the product which the user has added.
When the user submits the form, I should get an email with the list of values the user has selected. How do I achieve this in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$products = $_POST['product'];

$orderedItems = "Ordered items:";
foreach($products as $product) {
  $orderedItems .= "$product ";
}

mail("your@email.com", "Subject line", $orderedItems);
```

You might need to set up a mail server, or you could use a service such as [Mailgun](http://mailgun.com).

Comment: Unfortunately, the email just looks like this: Ordered items: [blank]